# how to find pixel color in custom view?

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, pixel

i have prepared one custom view using onDraw method,

my view class is,

```
public class MyAlphabetDraw extends View {

    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    public static Bitmap myBitmap;

    public MyAlphabetDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);

        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        mPaint.setTextSize(50);

    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
        myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                System.out.println("bitmaps ---"+myBitmap);
                canvas.drawText("Android", 50, 280,mAlphaInner);

        }

}
```

Here i converted view to bitmap using,

```
myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

after getting bitmaps i converted into pixels using,

```
private int intArray[];

intArray = new int[myBitmap.getWidth() * myBitmap.getHeight()];

        // copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array
        myBitmap.getPixels(intArray, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(),myBitmap.getHeight());

        // replace the red pixels with yellow ones
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("color is--"+i+" "+intArray[i]);
            if (intArray[i] == 0xFFFFFFFF) {

                intArray[i] = 0xFFFF0000;
            }
        }
```

here control not enter into if condition.sop printed color value always "0". Some where i done mistake...please me

Comment: You are saving your bitmap in `myBitmap` but fetching the pixels from `bmp`. Since you have posted snippets, I cannot be sure it that is right. Please check it that is desired.

Comment: thank u for reply..i have edited my post...i changed bmp to myBitmap.now also same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ans to your question is that you will get 0 only as in your code you never updated your bitmap with any drawing. All actions were just related to creating the bitmap.

You have to call apis like `myBitmap.setPixel(0,0,color)`.

Now if you want to use canvas to write to Bitmap. You have to create a new canvas. Here is the sudo code:

```
Canvas bmpCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
bmpCanvas.drawText("Android", 50, 280,mAlphaInner);

// change pixel values in the bitmap like you are doing above 
// or you should use bmpCanvas to change the values
// and after that

canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

Here you have the complete implementation, hope code walk through will help you:

```
package com.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class MyAlphabetDraw extends View {
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    Paint mAlphaInner = new Paint();
    public static Bitmap myBitmap;
    public static Canvas bmpCanvas;
    private int intArray[];

    public MyAlphabetDraw(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MyAlphabetDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyAlphabetDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    void init() {
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        mPaint.setTextSize(100);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        mAlphaInner.setDither(true);
        mAlphaInner.setColor(0xFF0000FF);
        mAlphaInner.setTextSize(98);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (myBitmap == null) {
            myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            bmpCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
            intArray = new int[myBitmap.getWidth() * myBitmap.getHeight()];
        }

        if (bmpCanvas != null) {
            bmpCanvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 100, mPaint);
            bmpCanvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 90, mAlphaInner);

            // Code to get copy pixels into int array
            myBitmap.getPixels(intArray, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(),
                    myBitmap.getHeight());

            // Sample code if you put false the image will have white border
            // if true image will have red color for white pixels
            if (true) {
                for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
                    if (intArray[i] == 0xFFFFFFFF) {
                        intArray[i] = 0xFFFF0000;
                    }
                }
                myBitmap.setPixels(intArray, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(),
                        myBitmap.getHeight());
            }
        }

        if (myBitmap != null)
            canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for replay,after using this code custom view was not displayed.parent view is emplay.....

Comment: I want convert my custom view into pixels and find which pixel has color(white) and replaces with red color.

Comment: after added canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null) view was displayed.but It was taken only one pixel(myBitmap.setPixel(10,10,Color.WHITE)) ...please help me

Comment: try running your code without the pixel color replacement code and also can you put some screen shots..?

Comment: sorry you cannot do on SO...but can you use pastebin or something?

Comment: [link]http://i.imgur.com/bOjaS.png.  Here i need find which pixel has blue color and store in ArrayList.

Comment: Thank u very much dude...u gave great help to me..it is working fine